# Running script at startup and exiting gracefully at shutdown

Tags: startup, shutdown, rc

I am currently running a script at startup using `/etc/rc.local`.  The problem is that during shutdown, it does not exit gracefully. This can cause (important) data loss.  My script has a SIGINT handler to finish all jobs before exiting, is there any way to start the script during startup AND send a SIGINT to the script (and wait for it to finish) before shutdown?

Note:  I could manually send a SIGINT to the script before shutting it down but I will not be administrating this server and there's no telling what someone in the future might do.

Answer (score 0):

First, `chmod +x` to your script.Then`sudo ln -s yourscript /etc/init.d/somename`,
`sudo ln -s /etc/init.d/somename /etc/rc0.d/K88somename`.When you input `init 0` to shutdown the machine,your script will be executed.
The same to rcX.d,X means the runlevel.
My OS is Ubuntu 14.04 LTS。
In my OS,it work as i wish（maybe other also be fine，but i don't try）.

Comment: I read a bit about rc[0-6].  I'm assuming it waits for the script in the rc0.d directory to complete before shutdown?  Does shutdown also encompass restarts?

Comment: @Mocking    Does shutdown also encompass restarts？NO！ If you input "init 0",the rc0.d whill be exec.If you input "reboot",the rc6.d whill be exec